# How to remove or only show part of the data received?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, esp32

I'm using the `ble_client.ino` example and I can't figure out how to only show some of the `notifyCallback` data. I'm getting three different types of data from one service UUID.

```
static void notifyCallback(
  BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic,
  uint8_t* pData,
  size_t length,
  bool isNotify) {

  static unsigned long lastPrinted;
  const unsigned long printInterval = 100; 
  if(millis() - lastPrinted >= printInterval) {
    lastPrinted = millis();
    Serial.println();
    }
    Serial.printf(" Data:%X", pData[16]); 

}
```

This is what get in the serial monitor

> Data:A9 Data:B9 Data:F5
>   Data:A9 Data:B9 Data:F5
>   Data:A9 Data:B9 Data:F5
>   Data:A9 Data:B9 Data:F5

I just want the

> Data:B9
>   Data:B9
>   Data:B9
>   Data:B9
>   Data:B9

to be shown. How to?

Comment: use an `if` statement  ..... `Serial.printf()` executes only when data is B9

Comment: the value with change. can't use `if`

Comment: You only want each first and second value and not each third? Or you don't have found a clear condition which values you want? You need to find out a precise condition, and use it in an if statement as jsotola proposes.

Comment: You say the value can change, but then you also say that you only want "Data:B9" to be printed.  Do you see how that is ambiguous?  So do you want it printed only when it is B9?  Or what?  What determines that it should be printed?  Can you see how that is an important piece of information?